# PhantomJS: how to catch the return error codes

Tags: javascript, yii, phantomjs

I am trying to catch the error code after I run a PhantomJS script;

```
$result = '';
exec('/usr/bin/phantomjs ' . Yii::app()->basePath . '/commands/netsniff.js http://' . $model_url->location, $result);
$result = join("\n", $result);
if ($echo) {
    echo "json:\r\n";
    print_r($result);
}
```

I always get this error, no mather what, if a url fails to load:

`FAIL to load the address`

Should I not get a `json` that contains errors?

Comment: show the value of `$model_url->location`